# How would I go about changing the font and size in this arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, text, fonts

I want to change the font size and the font style. The font is too small.  I have tried a few things, but none of it seems to be working.  How do I go about doing this?

Here is the window that's created:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/apTJY.jpg]

```
public class Questions {

public ArrayList<String> mind = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> energy = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> nature = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> tactics = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> identity = new ArrayList<>();

Questions(){
    pullMind();
    pullEnergy();
    pullNature();
    pullTactics();
    pullIdentity();

}

public ArrayList<String> pullMind()
{

    mind.add(" You feel more energetic after spending time with a group of people.");
    mind.add(" If someone does not respond to your e-mail quickly, you start wondering if you said something wrong.");
    mind.add(" If the room is full, you stay closer to the walls, avoiding the center.");
    mind.add(" You feel very anxious in a stressful situation.");
    mind.add(" You do not usually initiate conversations.");
    mind.add(" You usually find it difficult to relax when talking in front of many people.");
    mind.add(" An interesting book or a video game is often better than a social event.");
    mind.add(" You find it difficult to introduce yourself to other people.");
    mind.add(" You do not mind being at the center of attention.");
    mind.add(" You enjoy going to social events that involve dress-up or role-play activities.");
    mind.add(" It does not take much time to start getting involved in social activities at your new workplace.");
    mind.add(" You are a relatively reserved and quiet person.");

    return mind;

}
public int getMindSize()
{
    return (mind.size());
}
```

Comment: If you are displaying in Swing GUI then you need to set font size on its component.

Comment: What graphical library are you using? It might be good to add it as a tag.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to the code you posted at all. It should be the GUI that handle font and size for the String.

The following problem does show how to set font and size for JTextField:

[JTextField Size Changing When I Change The Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266461/jtextfield-size-changing-when-i-change-the-font)